# Why can't you post an answer after another has been accepted?

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, accepted-answer

It's really irritating, especially when you work to research a good response, and when you go to post the answer the page doesn't allow it because an answer has been accepted.

It also detracts from the quality of question pages in general, since just because an answer is accepted by a user does not mean it is the best possible answer and can not be improved upon. This is even more common with users who use the accept as 'thanks' for a speedy answer, even if there are much better answers.

I say revert this behavior to how it used to be, with continuing to allow users to post answers regardless of whether one has already been accepted.

Comment: Do you have an example?  As long as a question is not closed, you should be able to post an answer. Acceptance of an answer doesn't prevent further answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043030/how-to-print-a-semicolon-without-using-a-semicolon-in-the-program#24043078

Comment: Was going to post the following text: {Three ways I know of to get the same effect as

    printf(";");
    putchar(';');
    printf("%c",';');

are (corresponding) as follow

    printf("\u003B");
    printf("%c",0x3B);
    putchar(0x3B);}, as far as I can tell nobody had mentioned the escape character method. Kind of bugs me, now the only way is to leave it in a comment or edit someone's answer, which is frowned upon but tempting.

Comment: That question has been put on hold for being too broad which means unless the question can be edited to be on-topic it will remain closed and no further answers will be accepted.  This is `status-by-design`.

Comment: Should I delete my question then, since it is completely wrong?

Comment: I can understand a newbie's confusion about this and I share his frustration.  On more than a handful of occasions I've spent 5-10 minutes composing a thoughtful answer only to have it "bounced" because the question had been closed/locked/deleted/whatever.  I don't know of a good solution for this other than to have folks not be quite so anxious to close questions of this nature, where the question was perhaps naive but was clearly phrased and only "broad" in the sense that there are many potential answers.

Comment: (I see that the question has been reopened -- an extraordinary rare occurrence.)

Answer (score 5):

The question you referenced is "on hold" which means no new answers can be added until the question is improved.  Normally, there is nothing stopping new answers even after one is accepted.

Comment: Strange that by the answer box after I had typed my text in that it said something along the lines of "This answer cannot be posted because an answer has already been accepted.", perhaps I am just wrong or the text was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @rsethc: I suspect you're misremembering the text.